# Getting below error while inflating material arc in Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, exception, material-design

I am getting below error as seen in image shared 
Kindly check and let me know .
I am using Maps in Fragments and using Floating button to make use of different types of maps .

[Image of Error while adding Material Arc in Fragment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4DUh4.png)

Below is My Fragment Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutSalesPerson"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp"
        >

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/landIdSpinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:spinnerMode="dialog"
            >
        </Spinner>
    </LinearLayout>

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layoutSalesPerson"
        />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearlayout_arcmenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_margin="10dp">

        <include
            layout="@layout/material_arc_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Material Arc Menu Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/arcMenu"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    app:menu_open="arc_left"
    app:menu_scr="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map"
    app:menu_ripple_color="@color/colorAccent"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_maptype"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_map" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageview_mylocation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_mylocation" />


</com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu>
```

Have also added

```
   compile 'com.sa90.materialarcmenu:library:1.4.1'
```

in build.gradle of Android gradle file .

Complete Error Trace

```
08-10 15:36:31.965 21984-22113/com.example.fms E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
08-10 15:36:31.965 21984-22113/com.example.fms E/File: fail readDirectory() errno=2
08-10 15:36:31.965 21984-21984/com.example.fms E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                 Process: com.example.fms, PID: 21984
                                                                 android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:626)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:827)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398)
                                                                     at godrej.fmsapp.fragments.Map_Fragment.onCreateView(Map_Fragment.java:51)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677)
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600)
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                     at godrej.fmsapp.fragments.Map_Fragment.onCreateView(Map_Fragment.java:51) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.<init>
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:133)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:110)
                                                                     at android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton.<init>(FloatingActionButton.java:106)
                                                                     at com.sa90.materialarcmenu.ArcMenu.<init>(ArcMenu.java:57)
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:600) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:702) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:827) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:751) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:769) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:498) 
                                                                     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:398) 
                                                                     at godrej.fmsapp.fragments.Map_Fragment.onCreateView(Map_Fragment.java:51) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2080) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1108) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1290) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:801) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1677) 
                                                                     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:536) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
                                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
                                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283) 
                                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 
                                                                     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
08-10 15:36:33.377 21984-22113/com.example.fms I/CrashlyticsCore: Crashlytics report upload complete: 598C301C028A-0001-55E0-8809DA48724F
08-10 15:36:34.908 21984-21984/com.example.fms I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 21984 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace as text.

Comment: Please check now

Comment: It looks like you might be using an outdated version of the appcompat support library.